# Good typesetting practice for long equations

Tags: math-mode, equations, typography, best-practices

I have the following (quite horrible) equation in my thesis:

```
\begin{align*}
\frac{\partial^2}{\partial t_1^2} f(t_0,t_1) = 
( \delta+2t_0+2t_1)^{\alpha( w-t_0+t_1 )-1} \cdot \bigl(  
\frac{\partial^2}{\partial t_1^2}\alpha(w-t_0+t_1) \cdot ( \delta+2t_0+2t_1) \cdot  \log ( \delta+2t_0+2t_1) +\\
\alpha'(w-t_0+t_1) \cdot 2 \cdot  \log ( \delta+2t_0+2t_1)+
\alpha'(w-t_0+t_1) \cdot ( \delta+2t_0+2t_1) \cdot  \frac{2}{\delta+2t_0+2t_1} +\\
2 \frac{\partial}{\partial t_1} \alpha( w-t_0+t_1 ) \bigr) +
( \delta+2t_0+2t_1)^{\alpha( w-t_0+t_1 )-2}\cdot\\
 \bigl( \frac{\partial}{\partial t_1} \alpha(w-t_0+t_1) \cdot ( \delta+2t_0+2t_1) \cdot \log ( \delta+2t_0+2t_1) + (\alpha (w-t_0+t_1) -2) \bigr) \cdot \\
\bigl( \alpha'(w -t_0+t_1) \cdot ( \delta+2t_0+2t_1) \cdot  \log ( \delta+2t_0+2t_1) +
2\alpha( w-t_0+t_1)\bigr) = \\
( \delta+2t_0+2t_1)^{\alpha( w-t_0+t_1 )-1} \cdot \Bigl( 
 \frac{\partial^2}{\partial t_1^2}\alpha(w -t_0+t_1) \cdot ( \delta+2t_0+2t_1) \cdot  \log ( \delta+2t_0+2t_1) +\\
2 \cdot \alpha'(w-t_0+t_1)  \cdot  \bigl( 2 + \log ( \delta+2t_0+2t_1) \bigr) \Bigr) +
( \delta+2t_0+2t_1)^{\alpha( w-t_0+t_1)-2} \cdot \Bigl( \\
\alpha '(w-t_0+t_1) \cdot 
(\delta + 2t_0+2t_1) \cdot \log (\delta + 2t_0+2t_1) +  
\bigl(\alpha (w-t_0+t_1) -2) \bigr) \cdot
 \bigl(   \\
\alpha'(w-t_0+t_1) \cdot ( \delta+2t_0+2t_1) \cdot  \log ( \delta+2t_0+2t_1) +2\alpha( w-t_0+t_1)\bigr) \Bigr)  < 0
\end{align*}
```

Using this exact piece of code, without any special formatting commands such as & or \[2mm] the resulting mathematical text is quite unreadable:
[image: The equation]

How would you format such equations in LaTeX and what would you say is good practice when typesetting such large equations?

Comment: Either keep your `align*` or use a `split` inside a display-math environment, but add breaks in places unlikely to throw your reader off.  Break lines *before* plus signs, but *after* multiplication signs. For the latter, I think `\times` is easier to parse than `\cdot`, here. Also, use `\left(`, `\right)` for an automatic hierarchy in delimiter size; that will help your reader parse your equation.

Comment: You want to prove that this second derivative is negative, right? I guess there's no good _typesetting_ answer to your question, but my _mathematical_ answer is: try and give the proof more structure.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I'd try to make the equation smaller by grouping parts:

- Don't use `\cdot` where it's not necessary. I use it only for scalar products of vectors and for numbers, but not for symbolic factors or before parentheses.
- Derivatives are often written as `\partial_{t_1}` instead of `\frac{\partial}{\partial t_1}`. This can save some space.
- Introducing substitutions can be helpful. In your code `(\delta+2t_0+2t_1)` appears quite often and it could be replaced by a new symbol which will be defined before or after the equation
- Align the equation at least on all equal signs: `&=`
- Other line breaks may be before `+` signs to "group" summands (this shows that the equation consists of similar parts that are added together)

Answer (score 37):

[image]

breaking *before* not after operators and defining names for the subterms

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}


\begin{align*}
\frac{\partial^2}{\partial t_1^2} f(t_0,t_1)
 &= 
b^{a-1} \cdot \bigl(  
\frac{\partial^2}{\partial t_1^2}a \cdot b \cdot  \log ( b) +
a' \cdot 2 \cdot  \log ( b)+
a' \cdot b \cdot  \frac{2}{b} +
2 \frac{\partial}{\partial t_1} a \bigr) \\
 &\quad+
 b^{a-2}\cdot
 \bigl( \frac{\partial}{\partial t_1}a \cdot b \cdot \log ( b) + (a -2) \bigr) \cdot 
\bigl( a' \cdot b \cdot  \log ( b) + 2a\bigr)\\
  & = 
b^{a-1} \cdot \Bigl( 
 \frac{\partial^2}{\partial t_1^2}a \cdot  b \cdot  \log ( b) +
2 \cdot a'  \cdot  \bigl( 2 + \log ( b) \bigr) \Bigr)\\
&\quad +
b^{a-2} \cdot \bigl(a' \cdot 
c \cdot \log (c) +  
\bigl(a -2) \bigr) \cdot
 \bigl(a' \cdot  b \cdot  \log ( b) +2a)\bigr)\bigr)\\
  &< 0
\end{align*}
where:\\
$a=\alpha( w-t_0+t_1 )$\\
$a'=\alpha'(w-t_0+t_1)$\\
$b=\delta+2t_0+2t_1$\\
$c=\delta + 2t_0+2t_1$
\end{document}
```

Comment: I think adding a `\qquad` after the first and third line breaks would help the parsing.

Comment: `'` should be `^\prime`

Comment: @FooBar `'` is equivalent to `^\prime`.

Comment: @Jubobs always?

Comment: @FooBar yes (unless you define it not to be)

Comment: @David Carlisle, Thanks, didn't knew that.

Comment: Still I would combine more terms together such that the main equation can be set in one or maximal two lines. Then it is much easier to grasp what is going on.

Comment: Is it good here to use `\left` and `\right` as well so that the derivatives don'T go over the `(` and `)`? I think I'd prefere it when nothing goes over the paranthesis.

Comment: @FooBar or a bigger Big, you can't break inside left-right so as I was experimenting with breaking at different points that would have been a bit restrictive the matching brackets ended up on the same line but I didn't know that at the start

Comment: David: the place I think @Jubobs wanted a `\qquad` is still a `\quad`.

Comment: I might even put `is negative` on the following line, so the reader can't miss the `< 0`. If you keep it in the display, then be sure to repeat the assertion in the text.

Comment: Hmm, _mathematically_ speaking, `\frac{\partial}{\partial t_1}a` doesn't really make sense here.

Comment: @HendrikVogt yes I agree I used single letters as I couldn't tell how big the thing was (or what it was supposed to mean) originally, but the subterms are parametrised by (at least) t_0,t_1 so should probably be written a(t_0,t_1) or some such.

Comment: What's the difference between `b` and `c` in the formula?

Comment: @Mico Not sure what you mean? this is all 4 years ago, I'm just fixing the site corruption of `\\ ` in answers.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle - I'm pointlessly teasing you... You're doing a wonderful service fixing the double-backslash issues!! (FWIW, the `b` and `c` terms seem to be the same. No point in fixing this now, nearly 4 years after the fact!)

Answer (score 12):

Actually, I would like to start answering with a question: Is it very informative to display an equation that long?

I would try to identify parts in your equation, and write something like

```
\[a (A + B + C) < 0\]
where
\[a = ... \]
and
\begin{align} 
A &= ... \\
B &= ... \\
C &= ...
\end{align}
```

this makes it much easier to read it, and you can maybe give also an exlanation to every term.

Answer (score 2):

Try using the `breqn` package.  Begin with `usepackage{breqn}`, then replace the `align*` environment with `dmath*`.  Then remove all the manual linebreaks `\\`, because `breqn` does the line-breaking and aligning automatically.  Also you can replace `\bigl` and `\bigr` with `\left` and `\right`, because `breqn` allows line breaks within a `\left`-`\right` pair.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{breqn}  % from the "mh" bundle

\begin{document}

\begin{dmath*}
\frac{\partial^2}{\partial t_1^2} f(t_0,t_1) = 
( \delta+2t_0+2t_1)^{\alpha( w-t_0+t_1 )-1} \cdot \left(  
\frac{\partial^2}{\partial t_1^2}\alpha(w-t_0+t_1) \cdot ( \delta+2t_0+2t_1) \cdot  
\log ( \delta+2t_0+2t_1) +
\alpha'(w-t_0+t_1) \cdot 2 \cdot  \log ( \delta+2t_0+2t_1)+
\alpha'(w-t_0+t_1) \cdot ( \delta+2t_0+2t_1) \cdot  \frac{2}{\delta+2t_0+2t_1} +
2 \frac{\partial}{\partial t_1} \alpha( w-t_0+t_1 ) \right) +
( \delta+2t_0+2t_1)^{\alpha( w-t_0+t_1 )-2}\cdot
 \left( \frac{\partial}{\partial t_1} \alpha(w-t_0+t_1) \cdot ( \delta+2t_0+2t_1) 
\cdot \log ( \delta+2t_0+2t_1) + (\alpha (w-t_0+t_1) -2) \right) \cdot 
\left( \alpha'(w -t_0+t_1) \cdot ( \delta+2t_0+2t_1) \cdot  \log ( \delta+2t_0+2t_1) +
2\alpha( w-t_0+t_1)\right) = 
( \delta+2t_0+2t_1)^{\alpha( w-t_0+t_1 )-1} \cdot \left( 
\frac{\partial^2}{\partial t_1^2}\alpha(w -t_0+t_1) \cdot ( \delta+2t_0+2t_1) \cdot  
\log ( \delta+2t_0+2t_1) +
2 \cdot \alpha'(w-t_0+t_1)  \cdot  \left( 2 + \log ( \delta+2t_0+2t_1) \right) \right)
+ ( \delta+2t_0+2t_1)^{\alpha( w-t_0+t_1)-2} \cdot \Bigl( 
\alpha '(w-t_0+t_1) \cdot 
(\delta + 2t_0+2t_1) \cdot \log (\delta + 2t_0+2t_1) +  
\left(\alpha (w-t_0+t_1) -2 \right) \cdot
 \left(   
\alpha'(w-t_0+t_1) \cdot ( \delta+2t_0+2t_1) \cdot  \log ( \delta+2t_0+2t_1) +2\alpha(
 w-t_0+t_1)\right) \Bigr)  < 0
\end{dmath*}
\end{document}
```